# Connection between Sweeney Todd and Edward Scissorhands

Tags: edward-scissorhands, sweeney-todd

I have not yet seen Sweeney Todd, however, I did watch Edward Scissorhands and the poster similarity seemed striking. From what I have read about Sweeney Todd, I concluded that both movies involve main characters cutting hair and both being played by Johnny Depp.

So is there been any relationship between the two movies/characters?

Comment: Well, and they were made by (frequent Depp-collaborator) Tim Burton, which could be a reason for quite some stylistic similarities (as most of Burton's films have).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Or depending on your outlook they both contained frequent Burton-collaborator Johnny Depp.

Comment: The character *Sweeny Todd* has been around since the 1800s and the musical version that was produced (Sondheim's) was written in 1979.

Comment: @Pharap Sure, which didn't fit the writing flow of that comment, though, since he already knew about Depp.

Comment: @Pharap Except that Depp doesn't control any of the project. He's an actor not a producer or director... I like to think of him as Burton's Muse... but he had no control over the film other than his character.

Comment: Anyway, Sweeny Todd is a "barber" and his main job is shaving men's faces, not "cutting hair". Edward Scissorhands is the opposite.

Comment: @Catija - Although the film Sweeney Todd largely focuses on his shaving skills, I assume that a barber (even a demon one) would also cut hair :-)

Comment: Well the other day I was watching the movie sweeny todd and my cousin said the window reminds her of the room that the lady found edward in... anybody else feel that??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excluding the obvious connection ([Tim Burton as Director/Producer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000318/) / [Johnny Depp as Star Actor](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000136/)) there are two other members of crew who were involved with both productions

- [Ve Neil](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0624763/) (Makeup Dept Head / Senior Makeup Artist)
- [Colleen Atwood](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0041181/) (Costume Designer)

As you say, there are notable *thematic* similarities (Mr Burton's trademark faux-gothic look & feel is especially rampant in both films) but there's no clear connection between the two main characters. Sweeney Todd is largely a retelling of a Sondheim musical (itself based on a fictional character from a "penny dreadful") whereas Edward Scissorhands was largely based on Burton's own experiences as a child and his feelings of isolation. He did, however envision Edward Scissorhands as a possible musical film so there's some match there.

Comment: They are kind of opposites in terms of character.  Sweeney Todd is a ruthless serial killer, while Edward is just misunderstood, but a generally nice guy.  Sweeney kills his daughter, Edward kills his father (both by mistake, though Sweeney's case was one of mistaken identity, while Edward's was an honest accident).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman no, Edward did not kill Vincent Price. He died of old age/heart attack. Edward accidentally cut up the corpse and the new hands attempting to hold/catch him.

Comment: @cde - Maybe I'm remembering it wrong, but I thought he had a heart attack and Edward tried to catch him - but he might've survived the heart attack if he hadn't been impaled on the scissors...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, I believe Sweeney spares his daughter and kills his ex/wife through mistaken identity